# Laravel Eloquent create returning null id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an Eloquent model `Foo`, with a public `bar` array:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public $bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}
```

In the `store` method of my controller I want to access these variables, and create a new `Foo` object:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $foo = new Foo;

    foreach ($foo->bar as $field) {
        $data[$field] = $request->{$field};
    }

    $foo->create($data);

    return $foo->id;
}
```

The problem is that `$foo->id` is `null`, although the object is created successfully.

Comment: have you tried using the save method instead?

Comment: I would validate your request into a variable. instead of your foreach statement and you can create using the variable return from the $request->validate() method.

Comment: Just to avoid parameter injection or a mass assignment error being thrown.

Comment: Shouldn't `create()` be called statically? Like so: `$foo = Foo::create($data);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-assign the `$foo` variable because the `create` method will return the newly created instance.

```
$foo = $foo->create($data);
```